# What is the best practice to resolve issues due to updated revisions in Three.JS?

Tags: three.js

I have some codes developed using Three.js R52. I need some features in some code developed using Three.js R56. While I tried to add those features to the original codes developed in R52 and replace the reference to R52 with that to R56, it tells me some some error.

For example, in the original code based on R52, THREE.Matrix4().multiplySelf function is used. After I change the reference to three.min.js from R52 to R56, I came across errors saying:

TypeError: multiplySelf is not a function.

Then I go through the changes listed in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases by searching "Matrix4", I did not see any note related to method 'multiplySelf'. I searched "multiplySelf" and it returns no entry found. I searched three.min.js R52 and found function "multiplySelf". But there is no 'multiplySelf' in R65.

Could anybody tell me what I should do now? And in general, what is the best practice to resolve issues due to updated revisions in Three.JS? Thanks...

Comment: You are doing the right thing. Search for `self` instead. The change occurred in r.55.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create different sandboxes with the different versions of three.js. As such, I would be able to move from one sandbox to another and testing my functions without contaminating my code. I call sandbox a folder whose name is distinctive per three.js version where I only keep functionality relevant to that release and I never mix sandboxes. Usually you would have to keep a copy of your code in each sandbox until all the translations from one release to the other have been performed.

In addition you can use code like: `if (THREE.REVISION < 58)` to separate the different versions of three.js in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I can't Vote Up due to low reputation but I accepted your answer. Thanks...